# C++: ambigous overload can be resolved if typedefs are replaced

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading

Consider the following code snippet for vector and matrix multiplication:

```
#include <array>

template<typename T,size_t N> using vec = std::array<T,N>;

template<typename T,size_t N,size_t M> using mat = vec<vec<T,M>,N>;

template<typename T,typename U,size_t N> 
vec<T,N> operator*(const vec<T,N>& a,const vec<U,N>& b){
    return {}; //implement componentwise mult.
}

template<typename T,typename U,size_t N,size_t M,size_t L>
mat<T,L,M> operator*(const mat<T,N,M>& a,const mat<U,L,N>& b){
    return {}; //implement matrix mult.
}

int main(){
    mat<float,4,4> a,b;
    auto c = a * b;
}
```

I define 2 `operator*` overloads, where the second one explicitly uses matrices.

This will result in an "ambigous overload" error on `GCC 5.2`, although in my opinion the second overload is more specialized than the first one.

I now replace the typedefs in the second overload:

`mat<T,L,M> operator*(const mat<T,N,M>& a,const mat<U,L,N>& b)`

becomes:

`mat<T,L,M> operator*(const vec<vec<T,M>,N>& a,const vec<vec<U,N>,L>& b)`

**Edit:**

I made a small typo... thats why the resolution worked, I swapped `N` and `L`, so the type of `b` was `const vec<vec<U,L>,N>& b`.

Only with this typo the overload can be resolved normally.

My question is: Is this behavior welldefined by the standard or a bug?

Comment: *"Now the overload can be resolved normally."*, I can't reproduce, and I doubt the second overload is more specialized, given that the first one is viable only for arrays of equal lengths (this doesn't hold for the second overload)

Comment: I agree with @PiotrSkotnicki. It is not obvious as to which is more specialized.

Comment: Neither is more specialized here. You can add SFINAE to select the mat one for matrices.

Comment: thanks for finding out, I had a typo in my original code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With VS2015:

your code

```
template<typename T, typename U, size_t N>
vec<T, N> operator*(const vec<T, N>& a, const vec<U, N>& b) {
    return{}; //implement componentwise mult.
}

template<typename T, typename U, size_t N, size_t M, size_t L>
mat<T, L, M> operator*(const mat<T, N, M>& a, const mat<U, L, N>& b) {
    return{}; //implement matrix mult.
}
```

results in

```
Error   C2593   'operator *' is ambiguous
```

Ambiguity derives from the fact that in `vec<T, N> operator*(const vec<T, N>& a, const vec<U, N>& b)` T can be interpreted as a `vec<T,M>`.

And if I replace them as you suggested with

```
template<typename T, typename U, size_t N>
vec<T, N> operator*(const std::array<T, N>& a, const std::array<U, N>& b) {
    return{}; //implement componentwise mult.
}


template<typename T, typename U, size_t N, size_t M, size_t L>
mat<T, L, M> operator*(const vec<vec<T, M>, N>& a, const vec<vec<U, N>, L>& b) {
    return{}; //implement matrix mult.
}
```

the results doesn't change.

```
Error   C2593   'operator *' is ambiguous
```

Are you sure about your solution? Maybe you are not considering const?